# Angular material 2 autocomplete set key value

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I am new to angular material and I have an auto complete with nationality list, my country contains country code and value. I want to set country code If I select country from drop down and If my response is having country code ,I need to map this with my Country name in ngModel. My problem is I am mapping country code to my ngModel and I need to show Country Name on UI screen.

```js
<input name="nationality" matInput placeholder="nationality"  class="form-control" [matAutocomplete]="nationAuto" [formControl]="nationalityCtrl"
   [(ngModel)]="myModel.nationality" required>
 <mat-option *ngFor="let country of filteredNationalityList | async" 
          [value]="country.code">
 <span>{{ country.value }}</span>
</mat-option>
```

The same [value]="country.code" working for Select Drop down, But not working for Autocomplete drop down.

Here I have created sample. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pvqugs
Could you please let me know where I am missing. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The value in the answer from Mohammad is the selected country code, so just get the country by the code and set the value in the input field yourself by adding this line to optionSelected:

```
nationalityCtrl.setValue(country.value)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your code as follows:

```
<mat-form-field>

  <input matInput type="text" placeholder="nationality" [matAutocomplete]="nationAuto" [formControl]="nationalityCtrl">    
  <mat-autocomplete #nationality="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="optionSelected($event)">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let country of filteredNationalityList | async" [value]="country.code">
      {{ country.value }}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>

</mat-form-field>



optionSelected(event) {
    let value = event.option.value;     
    //this.propagateChange(category.title);
}
```

Comment: in that case material autocomplete will put the code in the input after the country selection.. I think that is not the expected behavior.